# Can't save changes or modify settings in Dashboard but Pages and Posts are fine

Tags: plugins, wp-admin, users, dashboard, warnings

I am working on a client site from a previous developer. It needed many updates so I updated WordPress to v.6.0.1, Astra theme 3.9.1 (uses a child theme) and the many plugins in use. After all this, there were no visible problems but several cropped up when using the Dashboard.

Changes to WordPress or plugin settings can't be saved or user details updated, even though the content for Posts and Pages can be modified. This is despite switching to the Twenty-Twenty theme and deactivating **all** plugins.

Some examples:

- Updating my admin profile did not save changes (e.g. added a URL and bio, both were blank when the form reloaded).
- As the admin, updating the editor's profile in the same way loaded a blank page with "*Invalid user ID.*" and no changes were saved.
- Can't bulk activate / deactivate plugins, the page reloads without any changes (though, manually one-by-one works or by changing the plugin directory name)
- Clicking *Save Changes* in most areas of Settings doesn't work but instead loads an **All Settings** page with the message "*Warning: This page allows direct access to your site settings. You can break things here. Please be cautious!*" and dozens of fields.

When Astra and the plugins were active, I noticed problems like:

- In Code Snippets, adding a new snippet wouldn't work. The page reloaded with a blank form.
- In Maintenance, toggling the enable/disable button had no effect (had to rename that plugin's folder to disable it).
- Login form created in Forminator wouldn't work after submitting, simply reloaded the page.

Using the default WordPress login works, though, even when White Label CMS was active. And all of the same issues exist in a staging version of the site I created.

In Health Check & Troubleshooting, the Info tab's Database info appears correct and the Filesystem Permissions are all writable. The Status tab doesn't show any issues that appear relevant.

I'm really at a loss here to solve the problem because it does not appear to be a theme or plugin issue. I do have an Updraft backup but I'm hoping this can be solved without restoring it. Doing so would mean redoing a lot of work.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Well can be so many things, normally the best is to deactivate first plugins one by one and test, the most probable is that one plugin is making this.
This is just one of the first things to check.

Comment: True but, as I mentioned in my post, this still happens while all plugins are disabled and with Twenty-Twenty activated instead of the Astra theme. I've deactivated the entire plugins folder so no plugins are even loading.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. In an attempt to optimize Astra theme's performance, I modified the PHP settings in cPanel > MultiPHP INI Editor based on recommendations online.

However, I wasn't careful enough with my changes. I had neglected to include M in post_max_size, using only a number.

After adding it, everything started to work correctly again.

Comment: Awesome to know. :)